# Getting most accurate timestamp for accelerometer data for microsoft band on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, microsoft-band

I am using the Xamarin.Microsoft.Band and Xamarin.iOS, trying to read accelerometer data of the microsoft band on iOS. I got the band client connected and reading 3-axis data. however, it seems the (BandSensorDataEventArgs) from Xamarin.Microsoft.Band doesn't have timestamp data. Is that true? Anyway to get the timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no timestamp associated with the accelerometer data.

Comment: but here it says it has timestamp http://www.snakechia.com/first-impression-of-microsoft-band-sdk-preview/